# Can't run a no-op function in qemu

Tags: arm, stm32, qemu

I am using [xpack qemu arm](https://xpack.github.io/qemu-arm/) which is a fork of [qemu](https://www.qemu.org/) with support for STM32 boards.

I am trying to run a simple program to get myself started.

I have my linker script

```
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)

MEMORY
{
    FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x08000000
    RAM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x20000000
}

SECTIONS
{
    . = ORIGIN(FLASH);
    .text :
    {
        LONG(ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM)) /* set the SP initial value */
        LONG(Reset_Handler) /* set the PC initial value */
        *(.text)
    }
}
```

my assembly file

```
.section .text
.global Reset_Handler
Reset_Handler:
    BL main
    BL .
```

and a c function, `main`

```c
void main () {
    return;
}
```

When I assemble, compile, and link, the generated memory contents are

```
00000000 <main-0x8>:
   0:   40000000    .word   0x40000000
   4:   00000020    .word   0x00000020

00000008 <main>:
void main () {
   8:   e52db004    push    {fp}        ; (str fp, [sp, #-4]!)
   c:   e28db000    add fp, sp, #0
    return;
  10:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
  14:   e24bd000    sub sp, fp, #0
  18:   e49db004    pop {fp}        ; (ldr fp, [sp], #4)
  1c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000020 <Reset_Handler>:
.section .text
.global Reset_Handler
Reset_Handler:
    BL main
  20:   ebfffff8    bl  8 <main>
    BL .
  24:   ebfffffe    bl  24 <Reset_Handler+0x4>
```

I am using a `STM32F407VG` MCU, the docs state that

> After this startup delay is over, the CPU fetches the top-of-stack value from address
> 0x0000 0000, then starts code execution from the boot memory starting from 0x0000 0004.

Thus, I store the initial value of the stack pointer `0x40000000` in memory location `0x00000000` and the initial value of the program counter in memory location `0x00000004`

I start qemu like so

```
qemu-system-gnuarmeclipse -mcu STM32F407VG -machine STM32F4-Discovery -image myfile.elf -nographic --verbose --verbose  -no-reboot -S
```

And I can see that the SP and PC registers (R13 and R15, respectively) are set to the expected values:

```
R00=00000000 R01=00000000 R02=00000000 R03=00000000
R04=00000000 R05=00000000 R06=00000000 R07=00000000
R08=00000000 R09=00000000 R10=00000000 R11=00000000
R12=00000000 R13=40000000 R14=00000000 R15=00000020
PSR=40000153 -Z-- A svc32
FPSCR: 00000000
```

So, following the memory mapping output, the program should flow like so:

- PC is set to `0x2`0, which runs `BL 8 <main>`
- This branches to memory location `0x8`, which is the start of the `main` function, it also saves the return address in `LR`
- This function should perform a no-op, with pushing and popping `FP` to/from the stack
- the function should return to the address of `LR` (which was previously saved)
- The next instruction should loop forever (`24:   ebfffffe    bl  24 <Reset_Handler+0x4>`)

However, I run this, and I get the following error:

```
(qemu) Bad ram pointer 0x4
```

I am a little lost on what this error means.  Am I missing something in my setup?

Comment: Can you not single-step to see specifically where things go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
 ORIGIN = 0x00000000
```

The memory is aliased to 0 by the hardware but the real address is not zero,

You linker script has to the use corrent FLASH address not boot time alias.

```
0x8000000
```

I would suggest to use stm provided linker scripts as you not exactly understand the documentation of the chip.